# Drawing different colors of circles depending if a number exists in a variable or not

Tags: javascript

So I got this jackpot coding. First it finds 7 unique random numbers between 1-36:

```
function RandomTal(Limit)
{
        var RandomLottoTal
        var Cont = true
        while(Cont)
        {
                RandomLottoTal=Math.round(Math.random()*100+1)
                if (RandomLottoTal <= Limit)
                {
                        Cont = false
                }
        }
        return RandomLottoTal;
}
function FindLottoTal()
{
        var min = 1
        var RandomTalNy
        var LottoTal = []
        for (var i=min; i<=7; i++)
        {
                RandomTalNy = RandomTal(36)
                if(LottoTal.indexOf(RandomTalNy)<0)
                {
                        LottoTal[i] = RandomTalNy
                }
                else
                {
                        i--
                }
        }
        DineLottoTal.value = LottoTal
        return i;
}
```

Then when I have to draw the circle something doesn't work. What I want it to do is it checks all numbers from 1-36 and if it is the same as one of my 7 random jackpot numbers, it has to draw a red circle, else it has to draw a white circle.
Circle coding:

```
function TegnCirkel()
{
        var canvas = document.getElementById("LottoPlade")
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        var LottoTalNy = FindLottoTal()
        for (var j=1; j<=4; j++)
        {
                var Tæller = 0
                for (var i=1; i<=9; i++)
                {
                        Tæller = Tæller + 1
                        XPos = i*100-50
                        YPos = j*100-50
                        if (LottoTalNy.indexOf(Tæller)<0)
                        {
                                // Color for white not yet added
                                ctx.beginPath()
                                ctx.arc(XPos,YPos,20,0,2*Math.PI)
                                ctx.stroke()
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                // Color for red not yet added
                                ctx.beginPath()
                                ctx.arc(XPos,YPos,20,0,2*Math.PI)
                                ctx.stroke()
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong or a fix.
Help is appreciated a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it helps, but I did not have much time to understand what you wanted to do

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Micio/nPxb8/229/)

```
 function TegnCirkel()
{
        var canvas = document.getElementById("LottoPlade")
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        var LottoTalNy = FindLottoTal()
        for (var j=1; j<=4; j++)
        {
                var Tæller = 0
                for (var i=1; i<=9; i++)
                {
                        Tæller = Tæller + 1
                        XPos = i*100-50
                        YPos = j*100-50
                        if (LottoTalNy.toString().indexOf(Tæller)<0)
                        {
                                ctx.beginPath()
                                ctx.arc(XPos,YPos,20,0,2*Math.PI)
                                ctx.stroke()
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                ctx.beginPath()
                                ctx.arc(XPos,YPos,20,0,2*Math.PI)
                                ctx.stroke()
                        }
                }
        }
}
function RandomTal(Limit)
{
        var RandomLottoTal
        var Cont = true
        while(Cont)
        {
                RandomLottoTal=Math.round(Math.random()*100+1)
                if (RandomLottoTal <= Limit)
                {
                        Cont = false
                }
        }
        return RandomLottoTal;
}
function FindLottoTal()
{
        var min = 1
        var RandomTalNy
        var LottoTal = []
        for (var i=min; i<=7; i++)
        {
                RandomTalNy = RandomTal(36)
                if(LottoTal.indexOf(RandomTalNy)<0)
                {
                        LottoTal[i] = RandomTalNy
                }
                else
                {
                        i--
                }
        }
        FindLottoTal.value = LottoTal
        return i;
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver. It now works. Do you have any clue why the other one without the "toString" wouldn't work?

Comment: @Henrik The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. Tæller was a number :)

Comment: @Henrik if possible check the answer's flag